# Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource

Tags: c#, list, datatable, dataset, enumeration

I want to bind the value of groups into DataTable dt1=new DataTable(). After that I want to bind the DataTable datat to DataGrid. But I am unable to do it. When i given the datasource to datagrid as groups directly then I got Exception of "**Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.**"

```
private void BindGrid()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Date",typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name",typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("City",typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Mobile",typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add("1/11/2014", "David", "Noida", "Bsnl");
        dt.Rows.Add("1/11/2014", "James", "Mumbai", "Airtel");
        dt.Rows.Add("30/1/2015", "Ramesh", "Pune", "Vodafone");
        dt.Rows.Add("30/1/2015", "Kamal", "Kolkata", "Idea");
        dt.Rows.Add("15/5/2015", "Mahesh", "Chennai", "Reliance");
        var groups = (
        from DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable()
        select new
        {
            date = row.Field<string>("Date")
        }
        ).Distinct();

        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

        dataGrid1.DataSource = groups;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind `dt` to `DataGrid` like so:

```
dataGrid1.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;
```

In your XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource={Binding}"/>
```

`DefaultView` is a `DataView`, which implements `IList`.

As far as the rest of your code, I've no idea what it is you're doing.  For example, what's the purpose of this line:

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
```

You do nothing with `dt1`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to add the value of groups into dt1 and after that I want to provide the value of dataGrid datasource to dt1

Comment: I want to filter the distinct  value of date into groups and the result of groups want to assign the DataTable dt1. After that i can provide the records of dt1 to dataGrid as dataSource.